# Send login credentials from C# client to Yii SOAP server

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap

So, I have SOAP handling classes from https://soapclient.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest. Using provided methods, I managed to connect to server and retrieve data, like:

```
SoapClient client = new SoapClient("http://somelink.someserver.net/~johndoe/gogogo/servis");
    XElement myEle = client.Invoke("getProjekti");
```

What I need to do next is to provide HTTP authentication i.e. to send login credentials to web server. There is a way of adding `Username` and `Password` to a provided SoapHeader:

```
client.Header = new SoapHeader();
client.Header.Name = "AuthHeader";
client.Header.Add("UserName", "student");
client.Header.Add("PassWord", "student");
```

And there's the roadblock for me. What to do next? Common sense and programming experience make me think that there should be, hypothetically, request method that will now somehow send that header to web server, like:

```
bool sendLoginRequestToServer(client)
```

or something, returning `true` if login is successful or `false` otherwise. Despite vigorous search I was only left puzzled, since many people use many methods, most of which I failed to understand. What makes it even more difficult for me is that most of tutorials cover C# WebService, while I have ordinary WinForms GUI application. Solution within aforementioned SoapClient would be preferable, but I would settle for anything that works.